# maven-assembly-plugin: Excluding files

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have this piece of code in my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>             
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>elcordelaciutat-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <packagingExcludes>***/*.pom</packagingExcludes>                                                    
                </configuration>
                                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but I have this error: `Element packagingExcludes is not allowed here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`packagingExcludes` does not [appear anywhere in `maven-assembly`](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/search?q=packagingExcludes).

And [issues related to `packagingExcludes`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-308?jql=text%20%7E%20%22packagingExcludes%22) involve projects like [`apache/maven-war-plugin`](https://github.com/apache/maven-war-plugin), which does declare [`packagingExcludes` in WarMojo.java](https://github.com/apache/maven-war-plugin/blob/94baefbbddaf64b944a0bb27be8e007ad5f15db2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/war/WarMojo.java#L78-L86)

So you might not have that option available for making an archive with `maven-assembly`.